# Syntax confusion in SQL

Tags: sql, average

List all products (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME) and their remaining stock (QUANTITY_IN_STOCK - REORDER_POINT). List only those rows whose remaining stock is more than the average REORDER_QTY value.

So far we have:

```
SELECT product_name, product_id, quantity_in_stock - reorder_point
FROM product
WHERE quantity_in_stock - reorder_point > avg(reorder_qty)
GROUP BY product_name;
```

The problem we're having is with the avg(reorder_qty), but we did some Google searching and looked through our text. Any help would be appreciated. :)

I understand it's typically taboo to ask homework questions, but we're not asking for the answer, but an explanation of where we went wrong that would lead us to the answers ourselves. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use aggregate functions like avg in a WHERE clause, since WHERE governs which rows go *into* the GROUP BY statement. You need to impose a condition on the output of the grouped data. The HAVING clause does this.

Answer (score 2):

The where clauses are looking to filter the rows returned by the from part of your statement.

it takes a while to get used to but really there are two parts to your question.. they both just happen to refer to the same source:

1.What is the average re-order quantity

and

2.do i have more in stock than the average re-order qty.

I would advise you try and do these two steps separately then try and combine them.  first what is a query that will tell you the average re-order quantity, then using that value as a constant try and get your bigger query to work.

once you have that working you will hopefully find it easy to substitute your fixed value with your query to get the value.

Comment: unless i misunderstand your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

When performing a `GROUP BY`, the `SELECT` can not reference any columns that are not also in the `GROUP BY`.  Further, any filtering that requires an aggregate function must be done as part of a HAVING clause.  Consider using a subquery to get the average reorder quantity.